# Which metric can i monitor for Azure App Service CPU and Memory usage?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have an 3 app servies running in an App Service plan in Azure. I am setting up a metric alert if the CPU % or Memeory usage on the App Service plan has reached a thresheold.
But I want to monitor each app service and the instances on each service as some have been scaled. The only mertric measure for CPU is CPU working set , but how does this monitor the CPU uage for the app service as the unit is in sec ?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement while navigating to your **App service >> Diagnose and solve problems >> Search for CPU Drill Down.**

[image]

You can monitor other App Services as shown in the below image

[image]